# How to get only id with onchange function in select box in angular 2?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

My code is in angular 8. When I add on change function in select box and get id. But when I console I got id in this form - 2:2. But I want only 2. Please help.
Html

```
<select
        type="number"
        class="form-control"
        formControlName="ServerId"
        (change)="onChangeServer(values[$event.target.selectedIndex])"
      >
        <option hiddenvalue="" disabled="true"
          >Please select Server</option
        >
        <option
          *ngFor="let server of getGpuInfo"
          type="number"
          [ngValue]="server.Id"
        >
          {{ server.ServerName }}
        </option>
      </select>
```

In ts -

```
onChangeServer(value: any) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

my output is 1:1

But I want output only 1

Comment: Can you show us what `values` contains ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select type="number"
        class="form-control"
        formControlName="ServerId"
        (change)="onChangeServer($event.target.value)">
        <option hiddenvalue="" disabled="true">Please select Server</option>
        <option *ngFor="let server of getGpuInfo" type="number" [value]="server.Id">
          {{ server.ServerName }}
        </option>
      </select>
```

In TS

```
onChangeServer(value: any) {
    console.log(value);
}
```